# How accurate the solution of over-determined linear system of equation could be using least square method?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I have read the theory of least square method. It is used to minimize the Frobenius norm of equation residual vector. but I searched the internet and I did not find how to determine the actual value of $||A\times x-b||_F$ during QR or SVD factorization. There must be some internal quality of matrix $A$ determines how accurate the solution could be.

Comment: The value of $\|Ax^*-b\|$, where $x^*$ is the least-squares solution, is simply how far $b$ is from the column space of $A$. If the SVD is $A=U\Sigma V^T$, then the value of $\|Ax^*-b\|$ is $\|(UU^T-I)b\|$.

Comment: because $U$ is unitary, the result could be the root of mean square of last few elements in $b$ ??

Answer (score 0):

The sensitivity of the method of least squares is quantified in terms of the matrix condition number in [Sensitivity of the least squares solution and the matrix condition number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912099/sensitivity-of-the-least-squares-method-and-matrix-condition-number/2176938#2176938)

The other questions weren't quite clear. Here is the best guess at the answers. The linear system
$$
\mathbf{A}x = b
$$
provides the least squares solution
$$
  x_{LS} = 
  \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} b + \left( \mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{\dagger}  \mathbf{A} \right) 
$$
If your matrix has full rank, you can solve via the normal equations to find
$$
 x_{LS} = \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{*} b.
$$
Or perhaps you have the singular value decomposition,
$$
  \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{U}\,\Sigma\, \mathbf{V}^{*},
$$
and can then construct the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse,
$$
 \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} = \mathbf{V}\, \Sigma^{-1} \mathbf{U}^{*}m.
$$ 
With the least squares solution in hand, the total error is
$$
 r^{2}\left( x_{LS} \right) = \lVert \mathbf{A}x_{LS} - b \rVert_{2}^{2} \ge 0.
$$